# Can't get symbolic links to work with the mklink command in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, symbolic-link

I'm trying to create a symbolic link in cmd (yes, I have admin privileges) like this:

```
mklink /D "G:\test" "C:\test"
```

The command runs without issue:

> "Symbolic link created for G:\test <==> C:\test"

In the test folder on C:, I have a txt-file, "new.txt".

Now, when I go to an explorer window and navigate to `G:\test`, I see my file "`new.txt`". However, when I double click it I get a pop-up saying:

> "Create new file" "G:\test\new.txt doesn't exist. Create it?"

The most frustrating this is that this has worked without problems before!

Please help.

/Zov